# Create confirm JavaScript for when users try to leave page without saving

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, confirm

I am trying to make it so that if a user makes changes to a page and then tries to leave the page without saving, a popup message will appear with an "OK" button (no "Cancel" button). Clicking the "OK" button, closes the message. The user must click the "Save" button or they will keep getting the message, prohibiting them from leaving the page until the "Save" button is clicked. By leave the page, I mean keeping them from navigating to another tab or menu item within the site...if they click any other link on the page, it would give them the popup. They can leave they site at anytime.

I am thinking I need JavaScript modal dialog to get rid of the Cancel button but am a bit uncertain of the implementation.

Currently, I am using r = confirm (see below) but it has the cancel button plus it gives the option for users to leave the page if they click "OK". I do not want them to be able to leave the page without clicking the "Save" button or they would have to close the entire window.

Any help/explanation is very much appreciated as I am very new to this. Thank you.

```
if (typeof unsaved != 'undefined') {
if (unsaved == true) {
var r = confirm("Please click Update. Unsaved changes will be lost.");
if (r == false) {
     saveNeeded = "true";
     }
     else { saveNeeded = "false"; }
 }
}
```

Comment: onbeforeunload and there is no way to prevent them....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [onBeforeUnload](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm).

You won't be able to force a user to stay on the website, however it will provide a pop up window with the 'Leave' and 'Stay' buttons when they attempt to close the window. All major web browsers allow the user to leave any webpage at will, and the most you can do is warn them. onBeforeUnload is probably the best cross-browser solution you will achieve to give users a chance to stay on the site and save their changes before leaving.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit() {
        return "Please click Update. Unsaved changes will be lost.";
    }
</script>
```

It would be very bad practice to attempt to lock a user to your website without an option of leaving, which is why it is not supported by any major web browsers. If it is so important that you MUST force the user to do something (and you have the right to as a company or such), you should use another platform or write a custom plugin to the user's web browser. But for general use, you can't lock their browser.

Comment: Thank you for your response and the link to more information. Users can leave the page if they click Save. I am not trying to keep them on the site, just trying to ensure they save their changes. The data can be deleted so if they want to get out of the loop all they have to do is click save.

Comment: Thanks for adding more clarity @TechEng. Unfortunately, you still won't be able to add this functionality, especially for a cross-browser solution. One solution that may work for you is to automatically save, and the warning as they are about to leave can warn them that it will automatically save unless they manually save or discard their changes (buttons on the webpage). That may be a way to make the warning work better for your application, from how it sounds.

Comment: @TechEng If you had been able to implement what you're asking for, what would have been the recourse for a user who makes a change on the form that they don't want (e.g. accidentally wipes out good data that was there before)? They would have to attempt to remember everything that was on the form before they started changing it, which might be impossible.

Comment: @OsakaWebbie, the form is broken out into tabs so there are not many fields per tab to begin with but yes, users could be forced to save bad data then go back and delete OR they could just make the correction before clicking save. Data comes in on a hard copy so there is always a way to circumvent what might be impossible. This feature was specifically asked for by the client and after researching options I thought I would ask to get feedback from others.

Comment: Nothing personal against your client, but I think they are short-sighted if they don't want to offer the user a way to cancel. But I hear you - you're just trying to code what they're asking for, whether it makes sense for usability or not. I've worked on government contracts - I know that feeling.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using typescript with an angular proyect, you can add this at the bottom of all your code:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) => {
  // set a truthy value to property returnValue
  event.returnValue = true;
});
```