# JavaScript alert when users try to leave page without saving

Tags: javascript

Following the question and the answer on 
[Create confirm JavaScript for when users try to leave page without saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086512/create-confirm-javascript-for-when-users-try-to-leave-page-without-saving/49577173#49577173)
the solution from MarkR

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit() {
        return "Please click Update. Unsaved changes will be lost.";
    }
</script>
```

works fine - except it asks me to confirm even if I click on the "Submit" button. I understand why. My question though is how to skip the execution of the code if the Submit button is used?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `beforeunload` handler when the user submits the form.

```
document.getElementById("formid").addEventListener("submit", function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have additional value `submitted` that will be set to `true` in case user pressed "Submit", but will reset to `false` when user changed any input on the page. That really depends on the type of application you're developing.

I assume you have `input` fields of different `type`, I would do

```
$('input').change(function(e) {
    window.submitted = false;
})
```

And then check `window.submitted` value in your `confirmExit` function.